# Apple Mach-O Linker Error even with the .m files added to Compile Sources of Build Phases

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I know this is some typical beginner question to use Xcode, but it's just confusing.

Basically, I git cloned a project from github.

https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

https://github.com/soulfly/webrtc-ios (forked)

Both projects are updated fairly recently,

> AppRTCDemo.xcodeproj    some refactoring    18 hours ago

and the readme says:

> To build XCode iOS app only:
>
> ```
> project location: webrtc-ios/ios-example/AppRTCDemo.xcodeproj
> Open the XCode project and set target for iPad
> Build and run
> Should work without changes
> ```

but, end up with many warning and errors.
Yes, I understand `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` typically occurs when *.m files are not added to `Compile Sources of Build Phases`, so I confirmed that.

It looks like the whole *.m files are included there (see the last attached image), so I know nothing to do more.

Can anyone give advice on this issue? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, the setup instructions in the git rep document that quite good: `To run example: Build this code for a device (iPad or iPhone).` If I build it for device it's running without any error (5 warnings). My guess is (as Igor's) that this project contains libraries which won't compile for the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are trying to build app to the iPad simulator.

Seems like this project doesn't work in iOS simulator, only on real device

Here is how Xcode looks like when I use real device - no errors:

[image: Here is how Xcode looks like when I use real device - no errors]

Here is how Xcode looks like when I use iOS simulator - lots of errors like in your question:

[image: Here is how Xcode looks like when I use iOS simulator]